# Cannot override proximity sensor on some devices, Android

Tags: android, proximitysensor

I am trying to make a custom layout for incoming and outgoing calls, and while the call is in the progress a specific image will be shown which has to stay visible even when user covers proximity sensor. I tried with wakelock but no success, now I am using proximity sensor which will just hide buttons and leave image to be displayed. This is working on some phones and all of the emulators but there are few samsung and sony phones that simply turn off the screen when close to sensor. This is my code for proximity sensor:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
}


@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Sensor sensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_PROXIMITY);
    sensorManager.registerListener(this, sensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
}

@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    float distance = event.values[0];

    if(distance < 4){
        buttonsLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
    else {
        buttonsLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Edit:

I am making calls with these:

```
android.telephony.PhoneStateListener

android.telephony.TelephonyManager

com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony (using reflection)
```

This is how I accept calls:

```
private void acceptCall() {

    timerLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    answerButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    startTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
    customHandler.postDelayed(updateTimerThread, 0);

    try {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("input keyevent " +
                Integer.toString(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK));

    } catch (IOException e) {
        String enforcedPerm = "android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED";
        Intent btnDown = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON).putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT, new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK));
        Intent btnUp = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON).putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT, new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK));

        sendOrderedBroadcast(btnDown, enforcedPerm);
        sendOrderedBroadcast(btnUp, enforcedPerm);
    }
}
```

Comment: you could try to hide the information from them, that there is an active call

Comment: To hide from devices or from user?

Comment: to hide from the business logic of Samsung and Sony

Comment: Yeah I would like to that for all devices but if I am making calls and ending theme programmatically how could I hide that from a device?

Comment: Could you please update your question to include which APIs you use and how you call them?